# How can I exclude the past (past days) using moment js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

I simply need to disable all past days from this date picker:

```
<DatePicker
   todayButton={"Today"}
   selected={this.state.day}
   onChange={this.onDateChange}
   excludeDates={[moment(), moment().subtract(1, 'days') ]}
   isClearable={true}
   placeholderText="Choose date"
/>
```

Dynamically subtract all past days.

Comment: is this a component from npm, maybe it has a minDate prop?

Comment: I don't think, here's the doc: https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/

Comment: Oh it has lol, thanks! fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright there is minDate prop.

```
<DatePicker
  todayButton={"Today"}
  selected={this.state.day}
  onChange={this.onDateChange}
  minDate={moment()}
  isClearable={true}
  placeholderText="Choose date"
/>
```